# How to retrieve and run an external javascript code using Ajax/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I'm stuck trying to solve this. I'm plotting some information that I have in one of my databases. Due my web UI, I'm using Ajax to call another page who make all the rendering stuff. In resume I have profile.php who lets the user select a grafic to render just passing the parameter ref via GET to stats-render.php. This is the partial code in profile.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr.table-row').click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({ url: 'stats-render.php', data: {ref: $(this).attr('id')}, type: 'post', success: function(d) {
        //clearInterval(loading);
        $('div.stats-data').html(d);
    }});

    $('div.stats-data').html('<center><img src="css/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader_IMG" /><br>Rendering your stats</center>');
    //var loading = setInterval(function() { $('div.stats-data')[0].innerHTML += '.' }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

In the other side, in stats-render.php I'm using the Google chart framework, that if you call the file stats-render.php directly it works just fine, the partial code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Visits');

    <?php
        $salida = "";
        $fgmembersite->DBLogin();
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT DATE(datetime), COUNT(1) as numVisits FROM stats_ram WHERE type='profile_visit' AND user_url = 'xxx' GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY))");
        echo "data.addRows([";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $salida = $salida . "['".$row['DATE(datetime)']."', ".$row['numVisits']."],";
        }
        $salida = rtrim($salida, ",");
        echo $salida . "]);";
    ?>

      // Set chart options
      var options = {'title':'Your CV visits by day', 'width':'100%', 'height':300, colors: ['#c7cfc7'], titleTextStyle: {color: '#5c5c5c'}};

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
      //chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height: 266, colors: ['#c7cfc7'], legendTextStyle: {color:'#666666'}0});
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, when you use profile.php to load stats-render.php it won't work, also the Chrome developer console will prompt you this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
(anonymous function)
e.extend.globalEvaljquery-1.7.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEvaljquery-1.7.min.js:2
brjquery-1.7.min.js:2
e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManipjquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.7.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.htmljquery-1.7.min.js:4
$.ajax.successprofile.php:97
f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.min.js:2
wjquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.djquery-1.7.min.js:4
```

I'm very sure that the Ajax call is working, and I'm very sure that stats-render.php is working also fine. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). It's designed specifically for this.